# How do I unzip a specific folder within a zipped file, and exclude some specific folder within it?

Tags: bash, shell, unzip

I have a zipped file:

`main.zip`

And I want to unzip only some folders present in the zipped folder while excluding the `.git` pack file.

The folder structure in `main.zip` is as follows:
`main.zip -> main_folder -> folder1, folder2...` and I want to extract only `folder2` from the zipped file, but this `folder2` contains the `.git` folder with packed files, which I don't need.

So far I have tried :

```sh
unzip main.zip "main_folder/folder2/*" -d ~ path/to/some/directory
```

`!(*.git)` will exclude the files ending with `.git`, but how do I integrate this in the command above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclude option works!

We just need to provide a path to the files to be excluded!

```sh
unzip main.zip "main_folder/folder2/*" -x "main_folder/folder2/*.git/*" -d path/to/some/directory
```